# rmi application

Tags: java, rmi

i want to write a rmi application which the server has the ability to run different programs like media player in the client, and even shut them down. how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by exposing client callbacks to the server (the client behaves as a server too in this sense), so that in response to some events the server can affect the client behavior.

Have a look at [this example](http://www.ryerson.ca/~dgrimsha/courses/cps841/RMICallbacks.html) for client callbacks.

A pretty common architecture for this is obtained through the use of the observer pattern - see an RMI [example here](http://www2.sys-con.com/ITSG/virtualcd/java/archives/0210/schwell/index.html).

P.S. If you have questions specific to media-players you should put that in a separate question, this will improve your chances to get a more specific answer.